# Java: My HashMap lookup fails because it does by REFERENCE, not by VALUE. How do I fix?

Tags: hashmap, key, hashcode, value-type

I am using a struct containing 3 integers as a key to my map.  It seems my HashMap is looking up keys based on REFERENCE, not keys based on VALUE.
Is there a way to fix this?
Below, **I am expecting b and d to be true!**

```
public class Triple{
    public int kid;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Triple(int a, int b, int c){
        kid=a;
        x=b;
        y=c;
    }

    public Triple(Triple notAcopy, int next, boolean reverse){
        kid=notAcopy.kid;
        x=notAcopy.x + next;
        if (reverse)
            y=notAcopy.y-next;
        else
            y=notAcopy.y+next;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "("+kid+", "+x+", "+y+") ";
    }
}

    HashMap<Triple, Boolean> forward;
    forward = new HashMap<Triple, Boolean>();
    Triple a = new Triple(1,4,10);
    Triple b = new Triple(1,4,10);
    Triple c = new Triple(1,5,11);
    Triple d = new Triple(1,5,11);
    forward.put(a, true);
    forward.put(c, true);

    System.out.println("a\t"+forward.containsKey(a));
    System.out.println("b\t"+forward.containsKey(b));
    System.out.println("c\t"+forward.containsKey(c));
    System.out.println("d\t"+forward.containsKey(d));

Output:
a   true
b   false
c   true
d   false
```

Answer (score 2):

Override hashcode and equals in class Triple.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:
Thanks to Timir.  This fixed it

```
For those reading at home, this fixed it
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return kid & x & y;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    Triple t = (Triple) o;
    boolean result = true;
    if (kid != t.kid || x != t.x || y != t.y)   result = false;
    return result;
}
```